# What are the best topics to learn for a first (and second) course in Category Theory?

Tags: soft-question, category-theory

I am a mathematics student in my last year of undergraduate studies and I'm taking a first Course in Category Theory. The professor that is giving the course is not a category theorist and because of the different backgrounds of my classmates we are advancing slowly (we have almost finished the semester). I'm afraid we'll not cover the same topics that are studied in other Category Theory courses. So far we have seen the definitions for

- category,
- concrete category,
- subcategory,
- retraction,
- monomorphism,
- epimorphism,
- bimorphism,
- isomorphism,
- functor,
- natural transformation,
- product,
- coproduct,
- small category and
- quasi-category.

I know we will eventually get to Yoneda's Lemma, so my questions are:

1. Are these topics enough for a first course in Category Theory for undergraduates?
2. If not, what are the best topics to learn in a first course in Category Theory for undergraduates?
3. I'm planning to take the following course, so I should better study ahead: What are. The best topics to learn in a second course in Category Theory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few huge gaps in that list I can see (also quasicategories should be removed), namely

- [limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_%28category_theory%29) and [colimits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_%28category_theory%29#Colimits_2) more general than products and coproducts,
- [universal properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property), and
- [adjoint functors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors).

You should absolutely know what these are after spending a semester learning category theory because people (not just category theorists) use them all the time. Beyond that (e.g. for a second course), it depends a lot on your interests. Some random possibilities:

- [monads](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad),
- [Kan extensions](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kan+extension),
- [monoidal categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+category) and [2-categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-category),
- [enriched categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+category) and [abelian categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/abelian+category),
- [cartesian closed categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cartesian+closed+category) and [topoi](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topos).

Comment: Quasicategories might well refer to something like non-locally-small categories (cf Joy of Cats) rather than simplicial sets with inner horn fillers.

Comment: Thank you! Small question: If my interests lie in the foundations of mathematics, what are some topics that I could study? I've read about groupoids, Grothendieck Universes and also about Lawvere's axiomatic system (ETCS). Do you know of other topics and the order I could study them? BTW: We defined a Quasi-category exactly as a category but with its objects being collections of classes.

Comment: @Jonathan: for me the term for that is "large category," and "quasicategory" means a particular model of $\infty$-categories (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quasi-category). If you're interested in foundations, you might want to learn some topos theory.